# Excute create table in SQL Server with C++

Tags: c++, sql, create-table

I am trying to create a table in SQL Server with following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    SQLHANDLE sqlevent, sqlconnection, sqlstatement;

    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlevent);

    SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlevent, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);

    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlevent, &sqlconnection);

    SQLCHAR retstring[10000];
    SQLDriverConnect(sqlconnection, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=SERVER;DATABASE=DATABASE;UID=CrystalReports;PWD=PASSWORD"), SQL_NTS, retstring, 10000, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);  

    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlconnection, &sqlstatement);

    string commandline;

    commandline = "CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE01(Name VARCHAR(10), Age INT, Salary DOUBLE PRECISSION)";

    if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlstatement, (SQLCHAR*)(commandline.c_str()), SQL_NTS))    // SQLExecDirect always failed to excute
    {
        cout<<"The create table sql command hasn't been excuted successfully."<<endl;
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

However, the code `if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlstatement, (SQLCHAR*)(commandline.c_str()), SQL_NTS))` always return a `TRUE`, which means the SQL command was not sucessfully excuted.

I've got all the permission to create a table, and I've check the SQL command in SQL server manually, and it works.

May I know what am I wrong? And how can I achieve my goal?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got answer since inspired by [C++ SQL Database program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153354/c-sql-database-program?rq=1)

I realised that there are different schemas in SQL Server, thus I use `CREATE TABLE [ROU].[NEW_TABLE01]` instead. Now my code works well.

Comment: Great, glad you could sort this out on your own. You can accept your own answer if you want to close this question.

Comment: @MiklosAubert I'd like to, but the system only allows me to accpet my own answer two days later. :-)